# Forming a tagline for customers, drivers and software

Tags: publishing

We are designing brochures for attracting possible vendors to use our software platform to attract/retain their customers.

The kind of vendors here are the hardworking type, with not necessarily any high education. We need the brochures to only excite them to call us. We should be able to connect to their one big problem, getting customers, and the loyalty. How do they attract the right kind of customers, and how do they retain them.

We have mobile applications that can connect the drivers with customers directly. Our mobile application and platform will take their services out to customers, and help them build loyalty. I am trying to build a tag line that connects them. Should be short and should only excite.

Basically I am trying to say `You have the drivers, metered taxi's, We have the software infrastructure and mobile applications to connect you to your customers.`

These are just too many words, I need to get as little words to graphically fit this image. I need help to reduce this and still retain the meaning and attract the people who have drivers and metered taxis to read this brochure.

[image: together]

Comment: Requests to rephrase a single sentence are [off-topic on this site](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/535/26). Can anyone think of how this could be edited into something on-topic?

Comment: In the interest of keeping the forum relevant, I have attempted to make the question on-topic. Let me know if I need to redo it again. Will be glad to.

Comment: Please dont vote me down, I have flagged it for moderator attention for deletion.

Comment: @Siddharth, since the question already has an answer we're not supposed to delete, but you can disassociate it from your account if you want.  If you do that, you'll have no further ownership of the question.  Use the "contact" link at the bottom of the page; that's something that has to be done by SE staff (mods can't do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say, "too many words."  Too many for what?

Do your customers have any insight that what they lack is software infrastructure and mobile applications specifically?  Or do they seek only some way to connect?

If they don't care specifically about infrastructure and apps, try:

> You have the drivers, metered taxi's, We have the technology to connect you to your customers.

The more abstract "technology" seems punchier to me, though less specific.  It shifts the focus to connecting, and away from the specifics of how you will help them connect.

Comment: Yup, this works for me.